# facebook app keeps redirecting after login

Tags: php, facebook

I made a Facebook application, but it keeps redirecting me to first index.php after I Login.
I tried all possible options that I've found here, but nothing seems to work.

```
require './facebook.php';
$app_id="367049733404736";
$canvas_url="http://localhost/fejs/";
$canvas_page="http://localhost/fejs/index.php";
$permission="user_about_me, read_friendlists, read_stream, publish_stream, user_likes, friends_likes, offline_access";
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" .$app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=" . $permission ;
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => 'App_Secret',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

and if user isn't logged in

```
 else {
echo "Welcome: ";
//echo '<a href="' . $auth_url . '">Login</a>';
echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => $permission,
            'redirect_uri' => $canvas_page
        )) . '">Login</a>';

}
```

User must first fill a form on index.php and after submiting it, index1.php is suposed to fetch some data from his friends. Every time i try to submit form, I get Login, and after I Login and try to submit form, I get Login again.

Comment: Change Your redirect url to your Facebook app url. Do you use mobile device?

Comment: same thing unfortunately:/

Comment: For the first time, fill the form and press submit, fill in your facebook login credentials and you will be redirected to some page. Now copy all the session variables[print_r($_SESSION);] of that page and display in comment.

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting everything in index1.php except the part I posted here and I added one echo just to know if the index1.php is oened. After clicking Login, I was redirected to index.php. After I submitted form for the second time I didn't get Login option and my echo showed. Then I added the deleted part of the code and now everything seems to work fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @lanrry Do not mention your actual appid and secret for security purpose in the code. And canvas setting , you can do it in your App dashboard of profile instead of writing in a page.

Comment: Please regenerate your app secret as you have removed the secret component of it by posting it here. Anyone can do malicious act with the same on your app's behalf.